# Azure Devops environment variable not resolving in task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

In an Azure Devops Build pipeline, I'm setting an environment variable in Powershell, like below:
[image: Setting the variable]

And i know the variable works in another powershell task, because of this test:
[image: viewing the variable]

But I'm not able to actually use this in another, non-powershell task.  See this docker build/push task where i'm trying to add a tag.  I get an error saying that it can't find that variable.  Is my notation wrong somehow?  I've tried multiple different variations on the screen shot below, but none have worked.
[image: docker invalid variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation `$env:LOCALTAG` is powershell specific. I think you should use the macro syntax `$(LOCALTAG)` (without `$env`)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables.

Comment: First option worked, guess i didn't realize.  Thank you!